Is there a way to prevent Word from interfering with my template codes when converting to html?
For a few specific things we use Word Documents as the template for php output.
Steps:

Convert word document to HTML
Add in {{tag}} or {[tag]} to html
Run through smarty or blade to generate new html document.
Works Perfectly.

Problem:
As it is nicer to edit a word document in Word rather than modify HTML text file, the document with {[tag]} can be loaded and edited.  However sometimes this results in word inserting tags inside my tag which breaks the template until it is manually fixed.
eg word will sometimes change
{[$myvariable]}
to
{ <span class="someclass">[$myvariable]</span>}
Question:
My question is there any form of tag or word eg {{ }} !!{{ }}!! etc that I can use that will not be split by word?
